# Set field unique on a specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing an app and I need some help with SQL relating these two tables

**Photos**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| idUser |
| photoType_Id |
| photoGuid |

**PhotoType**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

PhotoType is a table that contains info regarding if the photo is a profile picture, a banner, etc...

I don't want the database to allow more than one photoTypeID=1 per user

Is this possible with a UNIQUE Statement with a where clause?
If so, how could that be achieved?

I'm using SQL Server 19

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also just as an aside having one column be `idUser` and the other column `photoType_Id` really hurts my brain. Why camel prefix for one and underscore suffix for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique index with a filter:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX OnePhotoTypeID1PerUser
  ON dbo.Photos(idUser)
  WHERE photoType_Id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) As per the comment you made, it was the result of coding at 3 Am without coffee ahahah. Going to rename it asap. Thanks once again :))

Comment: Thank you..!! Was searching the same and got the answer.